# Предоставление ассортимента товаров в интернет-магазине через switch? Как использовать выход на главное меню?

Tags: java, веб-программирование, веб-сервер, интернет-магазин

Java. Есть интернет-магазин, классы товаров, конструкторы и т.д.

Также есть массив товаров.

В операторе switch предоставляется выбор, пользователь должен выбрать по числу товар на консоли. Хочу, чтобы пользователь мог выбирать несколько товаров, поэтому написал сканеры, - надеюсь здесь ничего такого нет.

Есть метод, который обозначает главное меню, называется в данном коде firstMethod();

Проблема с переходом в главное меню через оператор switch.

Когда нажимаю 1, 4, 5 и т.д. - товары отображаются, но когда нажимаю 6 то firstMethod (метод, вызывающий главное меню интернет-магазина (в данном случае под номером 6)) срабатывает, но в последнюю очередь, начинают просто по порядку высвечиваться товары и только потом срабатывает метод.

```html
   int i = Scanner.nextInt();
                switch (i) {
                    case 1:

                        System.out.println(products[0]);
                 
                       Scanner.nextInt();

                    case 2:

                        System.out.println(products[1]);
                       Scanner.nextInt();

                    case 3:
                        System.out.println(products[2]);
                       Scanner.nextInt();

                    case 4:

                        System.out.println(products[3]);
                      Scanner.nextInt();
                    case 5:
                        System.out.println(products[4]);
                      Scanner.nextInt();
                    case 6:
                            firstMethod();
                }
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что здесь не так? Как перейти на главное меню (вызвать метод, его вызывающий) с этим оператором, или лучше использовать другой? Если да, то желательно напишите код, чтобы я видел.

**UPD после комментариев**:

break тут ни при чем вообще. Выполняются все кейсы когда жму цифру метода (6). Выполняются ни сразу, по очереди. Жму 1, выполняется кейс 1, программа ждет моего ввода цифры. Я жму 6 и она почему-то выводит кейс 2. Потом еще жму 6 и выводит кейс 3, и т.д. break просто прекратит выполнение программы и преступит к следующему циклу или оператору.

Comment: _что здесь не так_ - нет `break;`ов, поэтому выполняются все кейсы, начиная с нужного.

Comment: Зачем ставить метки веб-программирование, веб-сервер, интернет магазин, если вопрос, по-факту, про switch?

Answer (score 3):

Если программа должна после каждого ввода выбирать действие, то чтение ввода нужно делать в цикле:

```
boolean isRunning = true;

while(isRunning) {
    int i = Scanner.nextInt();
    switch (i) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println(products[0]);
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println(products[1]);
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println(products[2]);
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.println(products[3]);
            break;
        case 5:
            System.out.println(products[4]);
            break;
        case 6:
            firstMethod();
            break;
        case 7:
            isRunning = false;
            exitMethod();
    }
}
```

И бряки тоже "причём"